# How do I create blocks from a road network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, network, polygon-creation

I have a road network and for every enclosed area within the network I want to create a polygon that represents that area. How does one do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an advanced licence, you can use the "[feature to polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003n000000)" tool to do this. Otherwise, you need some plug in. For instance, the free version of [ET Geowizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_NoRestrictions.htm) can help you.

Answer (score -1):

If your road network is the UK road network, then this has already been done and made available by the ordnance survey.

Simply go to the Ordnance survey "Open Data" site, you can download (or order on DVD) the Vectormap District (which gives you the road network), but if you scroll down the page you'll see on there something called the "OS Locator" which is a text delimited file (Not too big either) of north orientated rectangles forming a bounding rectangle around each discrete section of road in the UK (Some long roads such as the A1 have several rectangles covering it)

Comment: I was trying to understand the downvote.  The way the question is worded may be confusing: it appears it is seeking a way to create polygon features out of the regions wholly bounded by road features.  Your answer is also somewhat vague, but it appears to refer to bounding boxes ("extents") for road segments, which are entirely different things.